# Cannot find Laravel routes file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I started new project in laravel 5. Unfortunatelly, I can't find routes.php file in any folder. I dont have folders mentioned in documentation. Should I create it myself or what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel v5 and above, `app/Http/routes.php`.  You do not need to create it yourself.

Comment: In app/ I just have folders: Console, Events, Exceptations. Nothing interesting inside of them

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible.  Perhaps you should try downloading a fresh copy of Laravel

Comment: Reinstalling helped. Damn I should have tried it at first